# Cant give roles using python.py

Tags: python, discord

I am trying give people roles. I have made sure my bot can add and remove roles. Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.add_roles(message.author, "role id")
```

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jack Eagles\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Jack Eagles/PycharmProjects/Discord Bot/Main.py", line 71, in on_message
    await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
  File "C:\Users\Jack Eagles\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2907, in add_roles
    new_roles = utils._unique(role.id for role in itertools.chain(member.roles, roles))
  File "C:\Users\Jack Eagles\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 232, in _unique
    return [x for x in iterable if not (x in seen or adder(x))]
  File "C:\Users\Jack Eagles\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 232, in <listcomp>
    return [x for x in iterable if not (x in seen or adder(x))]
  File "C:\Users\Jack Eagles\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2907, in <genexpr>
    new_roles = utils._unique(role.id for role in itertools.chain(member.roles, roles))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: We're going to need to see more of your code than this. You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing that **add_roles**, in its second parameter, requires an object of some type that has an **id** attribute (data field).  Check the documentation or profile of **add_roles**.

Answer (score 1):

`client.add_roles` requires a Role object. It cannot accept a plain string

To get a `Role`, you should look through `message.server.roles`. Keep in mind that `message.server` might be `None` (In the case of private messages). You should not try to create your own instance of `Role`

Comment: Sorry but i have looked at the docs and still haven't figured our how to get the Role object, i am mostly just being stupid. So please can you help me

Answer (score 1):

```
# When a member joins, the bot DM's them a message
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
await client.send_message(member, 'Welcome to The Hangout {}, Enjoy your 
stay! Also, Check out the Icy Rules Homie!! :cookie:'.format(member.name))

# Assigns the joining member with a role
role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="")
await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Make sure to put the id number for the role you are trying to give to people. Also make sure you make the input delivery to the right person or whoever you are trying to assign it too.